# Localize custom element types

Tags: plugin-development, localization, elementtype

I explored the events plugin (from https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events) and I understand the most of that. Now I will try to make the events localized.

The Event itself has no localized field, just the fieldLayout fields. Do I have to save a second record in the event db or did I just have to save the element with the corresponding locale id?

Can you give me a hint what steps are needed that I can edit them in two languages?

So far, I load an existing event

```
craft()->elements->getElementById($eventId, 'Events_Event', $locale);
```

with the new locale parameter and create the edit form, putting the locale as hidden field to the form ('de' instead 'en'). The fieldLayout fields are showing the 'de'-icon above the input fields.

When I try to save it, I pass through the locale in the $event variable to
`craft()->elements->saveElement($event)`

I do not pass it to the `$eventRecord` because the $eventRecord itself didn't have a locale.

The event will be saved, just not in 'de' but in 'en'.

Do I have to tell the elementtype or the model that it can be localized to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I added this function to the Event_ElementType

```
public function isLocalized()
{
    return true;
}
```

This adds a language selector to your event index.

Then I enhanced the locale to the URL in `getCpEditUrl()` of the EventModel:

```
$locale = (craft()->isLocalized() && $this->locale != craft()->language) ? '/' . $this->locale : '';
return UrlHelper::getCpUrl('events/'.$calendar->handle.'/'.$this->id . $locale );
```

The additional route for the locale edit form is like this:

```
events/(?P<calendarHandle>{handle})/(?P<eventId>\d+)/(?P<locale>[-\w\.*]+)' => array('action' => 'events/editEvent')
```

Comment: phaetons, I am trying to create a localized ElementType myself. I followed much of what you mentioned here, and it'll let me edit in various languages using the ElementType picker. However, the only changes that are saved localized are the `Title`. Any custom fields are always globally changed. Any pointers? Or better yet, post your modified Events plugin code to GitHub?